# popup not working via javascript cookies - updated code

Tags: javascript, cookies

UPDATE - I have a page that has a popup, using javascript cookies (not allowed to use jquery) that will trigger the popup after 3 visits, 20% of the time, and only once every 6 months.  I have no idea why it's not working.  Please, please help. I'm a beginner with javascript.  (I've changed the url for identifying purposes)

```
//setting the expiration date to 6 months from now//
var expDate = new Date();
// in the following line, 180 means 180 days.// 
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 180);
//making the cookie//
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure){
document.cookie= name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin !== 0) return null;
    } else {
        begin += 1;
    }
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
    }
    return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
//cookie name is called CustomSurvey//
visits = getCookie("CustomSurvey");
if (visits) {
    visits = 1;
}
if (visits > 4)
//Math.random is set so that 20% of those visits actually get the popup//
    if ((Math.random() * (100 - 1) + 1) < 20) {
      //get location of where this popup came from; also contains variable from SM that will trickle down into reporting to tell where it came from//
       var currentLocation = window.location;
        window.open("https://www.surveymonkey.com", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    }
if (visits < 3) {
    ++visits;
    cookieData = visits;
    setCookie("CustomSurvey", cookieData, expDate);
}
```

Comment: There is a bug in your code, you are missing a double quote towards the bottom, the line for 

    window.open("https://www.surveymonkey.com, "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
    }

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in your code, you are missing a double quote towards the bottom, the line for

```
window.open("surveymonkey.com, "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

should be:

```
window.open("surveymonkey.com", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
```

Comment: In my real code I have a double quote at the end  - window.open("https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/XXXX?currentLocation=[currentLocation_value]" + "?" + currentLocation, "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");

Comment: OK, you should edit your question to reflect the correct syntax. It's misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not let you open a popup except in response to a user-triggered event (such as a click).

Too many years of sites firing off advert popups (or pop-unders, some of which triggered their own popups in turn) made users demand protection.

Comment: It worked before - i just added the expiration date.